# While loop runs when false

Tags: c++, while-loop

I've tried everything to I can find to get this to work. I've researched this an extensive amount and have tried every possible solution that I can find. I'm using QtCreator and coding in c++.

```
int main() {
    int Die1, Die2;
    cout << "Die 1: ";
    cin >> Die1;
    cout << "Die 2: ";
    cin >> Die2;
    while ( (Die1+Die2 != '2')||(Die1+Die2 != '3')||(Die1+Die2 != '5')||(Die1+Die2 != '7')||(Die1+Die2 != '9')||(Die1+Die2 != '11')) {
        cout << "You Rolled a " <<Die1<< " and " <<Die2<< " for a Total of " <<Die1 + Die2<<". Please Roll Again\n";
        cout << "Die 1: ";
        cin >> Die1;
        cout << "Die 2: ";
        cin >> Die2;
    }
```

Comment: In what circumstances do you expect all of those conditions to be false?

Comment: `Die1` and `Die2` are numbers, compare them to actual numbers, not character representations of number.

Comment: You are accepting integer values then comparing them to characters.

Comment: *While loop runs when false* -- You know that's impossible.

Comment: Your `while` condition is always true, since obviously Die1+Die2 can't be equal to both 2 AND 3 ! So it has to be different from one of them, not to mention your other tests ....

Comment: @KoleCichon *I have run it even when they are just integers* -- What exactly is the condition that you are trying to loop for?  I have a feeling you're trying to write your condition in the way we speak English instead of using logical `and`'s and `or`'s, *i.e.* boolean logic.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I wanted the loop to run if the sum of Die1 and Die2 was not equal to 2,3,5,7,9, or 11. However the question was answered by Neilkakkar down below.

Comment: @KoleCichon If you take a look at the answer and my last comment, you did exactly as I thought you were doing.  You wrote the test in "English-speak" instead of using boolean logic.  Note you used `||` (or) when you should have used `&&` (and).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you are right about the "English-Speak" it made more sense in my head than it did in the code. I'm rather new to C++ and this is my first programming course.

Comment: @KoleCichon -- Don't be surprised, You're not the first one to make this mistake of using "or" in a speaking sense when writing conditional statements.

Comment: DeMorgan's Law - it's not just a good idea.  I like to use it on boolean expressions like this as a sanity check to see if the "else/not" condition ALSO makes sense, i.e. X==2 AND X==3 AND X==5 AND ...  Doh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check your while condition!

Since the conditions are in the negation, you would use AND ( && ) instead of OR (||) to combine them.

**EDIT:**
And as pointed out, you ought to be comparing Die1 and Die2 to numbers. If you'd like to keep the characters as is, you could add character '0' to the sum of Die1 and Die2.

This seems to work fine:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int Die1, Die2;
    cout << "Die 1: ";
    cin >> Die1;
    cout << "Die 2: ";
    cin >> Die2;
    while ( (Die1+Die2 != 2)&&(Die1+Die2 != 3)&&(Die1+Die2 != 5)&&(Die1+Die2 != 7)&&(Die1+Die2 != 9)&&(Die1+Die2 != 11)) {
        cout << "You Rolled a " <<Die1<< " and " <<Die2<< " for a Total of " <<Die1 + Die2<<". Please Roll Again\n";
        cout << "Die 1: ";
        cin >> Die1;
        cout << "Die 2: ";
        cin >> Die2;
    }
```

}

Comment: Thank you, I changed it back to integers and replaced the or statements with and statements and the loop works properly!

Answer (score 3):

Your code:

```
(Die1+Die2 != '2') ||
(Die1+Die2 != '3') ||
(Die1+Die2 != '5') ||
(Die1+Die2 != '7') ||
(Die1+Die2 != '9') ||
(Die1+Die2 != '11')
```

Will evaluate to:

```
A.
( 1+1 != 2 ) = false
( 1+1 != 3 ) = true
break;

B.
( 1+2 != 2 ) = true
break;

C.
( 1+3 != 2 ) = true
break;

...
( 1 + ( x>2 ) != 2 ) = true
```

Your logic here is inherently flawed, in that it will *always* evaluate to *true*.

*edit*

As it has been pointed out by others, you are also trying to compare these integers to their `char` values, which will not align how you expect them to.

```
'0' = (hex)0x30 = (int)48
'1' = (hex)0x31 = (int)49
'2' = (hex)0x32 = (int)50
...
```

To fix this, you should be doing your comparisons to the actual number:

```
( Die1 + Die2 != 2 )
```

Comment: He's not comparing them to character literals, but string literals. And that's not the value of any of those literals when converted to integers...

Comment: While _also_ correct, the logic is still incorrect; which is my point of the answer. OP _should_ be able to fix the syntax error.

Comment: There we go, I've added a slight bit more details description to add to your point.

Comment: ...er, *you're* comparing them to their char value. *He's* comparing them to the integer you get when you cast the `const char *` of the string literal to an integer type. [They're rather different](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b31c1957395cc31).

Comment: @jaggedSpire I think I am missing what you mean by your last comment. I think I am trying to say the same thing, that `'2'` == `0x32` == `50`

Comment: OP is comparing an integer to a string literal, like `0 != ""`. You're comparing to a *character* literal, like `0 != ' '`. They're different things. Note the different quotes (string literals have double quotes, character literals have single quotes) String literals have the type `const char *`, and character literals have the type `char`.

Comment: @jaggedSpire my appologies, If you check the revisions of the question, a third party has changed the syntax. I am going to roll it back.

Comment: @MattClark Not a third party, but the OP.

Comment: oops, it was.. well I answered based on the original question, and my original part of the answer still stands. The _logic_ behind the statement is incorrect. There is just much more that is additionally incorrect.

Comment: @MattClark Maybe a sufficient addition would be to state that both string and character literals are incorrect here? OP seems to have made *both* mistakes, after all, even if in different edits.